# Как перебрать Erlang ETS таблицу

Tags: erlang

Доброго времени суток.
Разбираюсь с ETS таблицами в Erlang

Хочу проверить таблицу перебором, и проверить каждую запись (время по юниксу).
Не хочу использовать матчинг (ets:select(food, ets:fun2ms(fun(N = #food{calories=C}) when C < 600 -> N end)).)

Вместо этого пробую проверять через ets:next функцию. При этом данная функция возвращает только ключь записи, чего не достаточно для дальнейшей проверки.

Подскажите, или покажите где можно найти информацию о том как получить полные данные строки в таблице через ets:new / ets:first / ets:last

Может я вообще изначально не правильно создаю таблицу
ets:new(auth, [ordered_set]).

Comment: А можете описать задачу, а не решение?

Comment: Нужно удалять старые записи из ETS методом перебора каждой записи, а не через ets:select

Comment: старые по времени? Или есть другой критерий старости?

Comment: Да, при инсерте в таблицу - я записываю вместе с данными еще текущее время + время жизни записи (в юникстайм)

Comment: А если писать не время жизни, а время кода запись уже недействительна? Тогда будет проще фильтровать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено.

FromTime / ToTime - {{2017,1,13},{14,15,11}} переводим в datetime_to_gregorian_seconds сначала

```
FromSec = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(FromTime),
ToSec = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(ToTime),
```

Дальше вызываем функцию  - `lookup_by_date(FromTime, ToTime)`

Код:

```
lookup_by_date(FromTime, ToTime) -> lookup_by_date(FromTime, ToTime, ets:first(auth), []).
lookup_by_date(_FromTime, _ToTime, '$end_of_table', Acc) -> {reply, Acc, ok};
lookup_by_date(FromTime, ToTime, Key, Acc) ->
    case ets:lookup(auth, Key) of
        [{Login, Pass, TTL, Unix, Unix2}] ->
            F = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(Unix2),
        T = calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(Unix2),
        if
            F >= FromTime, T =< ToTime -> NewAcc = [{Login, Pass, TTL, Unix, Unix2}|Acc],
        N = ets:next(auth, Key),
            lookup_by_date(FromTime, ToTime, N, NewAcc);
        true -> N = ets:next(auth, Key),
                    lookup_by_date(FromTime, ToTime, N, Acc)
         end
        end.
```

Comment: пожалуйста, пометьте вопрос как принятый, что бы другие смогли использовать его

Comment: Сделал. новый человек тут, еще не все нюансы знаю :)